# Is there an open data set for PEOs?

Tags: data-request, business

I’m looking for open data set(s) for Professional Employer Organizations (PEOs).

I would hope to see fields like:

- PEO Business Name
- Headquarters Address
- States Covered: The US states where the PEO can co-employ worksite employees
- Certifications: Such as IRS Certification PEO, ESAC Accreditation, etc.
- Number of Worksite Employees Covered
- Year Founded
- Industry Specializations: Key industries served such as Healthcare, Manufacturing, Technology etc.
- Services Offered: Payroll, HR, Benefits, Compliance, Safety & Risk Management etc.
- Revenue
- Ownership Structure: Private, Public, Woman-owned, Minority-owned, Veteran-owned etc.
- Client Retention Rates Percentage
- Insurance Carrier Ratings
- Compliance Metrics: Audits, Inspections, Violations etc. related to workplace safety, labor laws